# Bootstrap columns are not stacking

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my classes `.fam-col-right` and `.fam-col-left` I am using `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; float: none;` in my css to vertically center the content I have as seen below. The `.row` is set to `display: table;`.

[image]

The problem I'm having is my columns aren't stacking at all and I'm not sure why. Here is what it looks like instead of it stacking.

[image]

How can I have my content stack and stay vertically aligned to the middle?

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Families -->
<div id="families">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center center-row">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6 fam-col-left">
            <h2>Families & Individuals</h2>
            <br>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus earum dolorum sapiente quod, voluptas optio, ducimus nemo rerum commodi porro laudantium nam. Veritatis ex enim culpa voluptatem, corporis? Distinctio, obcaecati.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 fam-col-right">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
             <li><i class="fa fa-map-o fa-fw fa-1x"></i><a href="#"> Wealth Management</a></li>
             <li><i class="fa fa-pie-chart fa-fw fa-1x"></i><a href="#"> Asset Allocation</a></li>
             <li><i class="fa fa-anchor  fa-fw fa-1x"></i><a href="#"> Insurance Risk Assessments</a></li>
             <li><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-fw fa-1x"></i><a href="#"> Education Funds Planning</a></li>
             <li><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-fw fa-1x"></i><a href="#"> Retirement Planning</a></li>
             <li><i class="fa fa-area-chart fa-fw fa-1x"></i><a href="#"> Investments</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- end row -->
</div> <!-- end container-fluid -->
</div> <!-- end families -->

.center-row {
display: table;
}

#families {
margin-bottom: -30px;
}

.fam-col-left {
background: url('../img/space.jpg');
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;

height: 550px;
color: #FCFFF5; /*white*/

display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
float: none;
}

.fam-col-left p {
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.fam-col-right {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
float: none;
}

.fam-col-right li {
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: you are making `float: none;` for the columns.so they wont stack as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking for something like this? - https://jsfiddle.net/9s1e9tm0/

```
.center-row {
display: table;
}

#families {
margin-bottom: -30px;
}

.fam-col-left {
background: url('http://www.unoosa.org/res/timeline/index_html/space-2.jpg');
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;

height: 550px;
color: #FCFFF5; /*white*/

display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
float: none;
width:50%;
}

.fam-col-left p {
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.fam-col-right {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
float: none;
width:50%;
}

.fam-col-right li {
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: It's better but I would prefer if they stocked on top of eachother.

Comment: don't know if i got your query correctly, you meant something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/9s1e9tm0/1/ please detail if not

Comment: When viewing on a mobile device or tablet I would like the img to be on top and the list to be on the bottom. I only want them to be side by side when viewing on a laptop or desktop.